# Image Resizing from an Array

Tags: php, arrays, image-processing, image-resizing

I am getting Image URL from the DB like this "image01-v2-70-70.jpg".

It is already scaled to 70-70, so I am getting it as smaller image.

I want to scale this image to 120-120 from its default 70-70

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean there is a 120-120 already saved or you want to scale up the existing image?

Comment: Probably? You have given us absolutely no usable information with which to answer this question, so you might want to edit it before it gets closed.

Comment: @DavidJones it is not already saved. I want to scale it to 120-120 from its default 70-70

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a php extension php image magick

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image01-v2-70-70.jpg');
$image->adaptiveResizeImage(120,120);

echo $image;
```

But this is highly not recomended as you are going from a smaller resolution to a larger resolution which will make the image blurry.

A piece of advice try to make a copy 120X120 resolution from the original image

Comment: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/
use the above tutorial